# Do sorcery points made from converted spell slots vanish after a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, spell-slots, rests

I was wondering about the sorcerer's ability to turn sorcery points into spell slots, where the same conversion rate applies to turn spell slots into sorcery points.

If, by the end of the day, you have unused spell slots and you want to risk the overnight ambush, could you turn them into sorcery points to be used the next day? Or would they disappear anyway?

Sorcery points are replenished after a long rest, but that only infers to ones that have been expended, and ones created by spell slots are theoretically one-use, so do they disappear daily or can they stack?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour].

Comment: Side note: the conversion rates for slots-to-points and points-to-slots aren't the same, iirc.

Comment: @GregMartin: Correct. Converting spell slots to sorcery points grants you a number of SP equal to the slot level, but it costs more SP to create a slot of a given level (2 SP to make a 1st-level slot, 3 SP for 2nd-level, 5 SP for 3rd-level, 6 for 4th-level, and 7 for 5th-level).

Answer (score 19):

### Sorcery points are replenished to a maximum.

You may convert your unused spell slots into sorcery points before taking a long rest, however they cannot exceed your maximum.

Upon waking all sorcery points will be replenished, to your maximum and no more.

> You can never have more sorcery points than shown on the table for
> your level. You regain all spent sorcery points when you finish a long
> rest. PHB 101

Answer (score 9):

The situation you describe is not something that would actually be beneficial.

Sorcerers cannot accumulate more sorcery points than what's listed on their chart for their level. Per the Sorcery Points class feature:

> You can never have more sorcery points than shown on the table for your level. You regain all spent sorcery points when you finish a long rest.

Since you can't exceed the fixed number, it doesn't benefit you to try and mass convert spell slots.

Comment: I've undeleted on assumption that is was self-deleted for guessing the system, but that it did guess correctly. If I'm wrong about that feel free to redelete, otherwise just flag this as NLN.